# AutoCompleteTextView displays incorrect strings from a SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider with a MergeCursor

Tags: android, kotlin

I am implementing a custom search screen in an Android app, and have setup an AutoCompleteTextView, and setup a cursor to my SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider so that these suggestions are displayed for the AutoCompleteTextView.

This works correctly when the cursor is only to the SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider, however I want to include some custom suggestions, so have set up a MergeCursor to do this.

When I do this, my custom suggestions are displayed correctly, but the suggestions from the SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider are displayed as "android.resource://system/17301578".

Clicking on a suggestion does add the correct text to the AutoCompleteTextView, and stepping through the CursorToStringConverter confirms that they are being correctly converted, yet for some reason these display incorrectly in the drop down list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have been unable to find any one who has had a similar issue, or even many examples of others trying to include custom suggestions with a SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider.

Here is the code that adds suggestions to the AutoCompleteTextView:

```kotlin
// Get a cursor to the SearchSuggestionsProvider
val uri =
    Uri.parse("content://" + SearchSuggestionsProvider.AUTHORITY + "/" + SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY)
val projection = arrayOf("_id", SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY)
val suggestionCursor =
    this.context?.contentResolver?.query(uri, projection, null, arrayOf(""), null)

// Set up autocomplete for special suggestions
val specialSuggestions = mutableListOf<String>()
specialSuggestions.add("Norfolk Island")
specialSuggestions.add("Pitcairn Island")

// Create a matrix cursor for the new entries, and use a merge cursor to return it with the recent searches
val matrixCursor = MatrixCursor(projection)
for ((i, suggestion) in specialSuggestions.withIndex()) {
    matrixCursor.newRow()
        .add("_id", i)
        .add(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY, suggestion)
}

// Set up the merge cursor
val cursor = MergeCursor(arrayOf(matrixCursor, suggestionCursor))

// Set up an adapter to the cursor
val adapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this.context,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    cursor,
    arrayOf(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY),
    intArrayOf(android.R.id.text1),
    SearchManager.FLAG_QUERY_REFINEMENT
)

// This ensures that the row in the cursor is returned as the suggestion string
adapter.cursorToStringConverter = SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter { cur ->
    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY))
}

// This adds filtering based on what the user has typed
adapter.filterQueryProvider = FilterQueryProvider { text ->
    val filterSuggestionCursor = this.context?.contentResolver?.query(
        uri,
        projection,
        null,
        arrayOf(text.toString()),
        null
    )
    val filterMatrixCursor = MatrixCursor(projection)
    for ((i, suggestion) in specialSuggestions.filter { s -> s.contains(text, true) }.withIndex()) {
        filterMatrixCursor.newRow()
            .add("_id", i)
            .add(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY, suggestion)
    }
    MergeCursor(arrayOf(filterMatrixCursor, filterSuggestionCursor))
}

// Add the adapter to the AutoCompleteTextView
val keywordsInput = view.findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.search_keywords_input)
keywordsInput.setAdapter(adapter)
```

Here is the portion of view for the search box:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:hint="Add Search Keywords..."
    app:endIconCheckable="true"
    android:id="@+id/search_keywords"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:endIconDrawable="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    app:endIconMode="custom"
    app:endIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:endIconContentDescription="Add Keyword">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.AutoCompleteTextView.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/search_keywords_input" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of the bug in action:

[image: Screenshot showing the issue]

Comment: With a little bit of digging, it seems that "android.resource://system/17301578" refers to `com.android.internal.R.drawable.ic_menu_recent_history`, which is in the `SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1` column. My projection doesn't contain this column, so I am not sure how it is getting there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you use a MergeCursor with your a MatrixCursor and SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider, you need all of the columns from the SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider, and in the same order.

The SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider's projection gets applied afterwards, it seems (I was thinking that the MergeCursor would merge the projection with my MatrixCursor).

To solve the problem, I changed the MatrixCursor constructor to:

```kotlin
val filterMatrixCursor = MatrixCursor(filterSuggestionCursor?.columnNames)
```